# AutoLayout failing when setting height of UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create a auto-sizing UITableViewCell with an image and a label, using constraints. When I define a height for the image, the height for the label isn't set correctly for some cells, why is that?

The image below shows a cell with a label that has an incorrect height and one which has a correct height.

[image]

The code for my custom cell with the contraints is:

```
import UIKit

class NewsItemCell : UITableViewCell {

   var msg: UILabel
   var img: UIImageView!

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

      msg = UILabel()
      msg.numberOfLines = 0
      msg.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
      msg.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

      img = UIImageView()
      img.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
      img.clipsToBounds = true

      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {

      super.awakeFromNib()

      addSubview(msg)
      addSubview(img)

      contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
      msg.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
      img.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

      let c0 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Top,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
      let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Leading,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
      let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
      let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: msg, attribute: .Top,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: img, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)
      let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: msg, attribute: .Bottom,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -5)
      let c5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: img, attribute: .Height,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 120)
      let c6 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: msg, attribute: .Trailing,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant:-5)
      let c7 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: msg, attribute: .Leading,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant:5)

      addConstraint(c0)
      addConstraint(c1)
      addConstraint(c2)
      addConstraint(c3)
      addConstraint(c4)
      addConstraint(c5)
      addConstraint(c6)
      addConstraint(c7)
  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Comment: Try layoutIfNeed() after adding the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Well there you see, asking if half the solution ^.^

It turned out that I was updating the `msg.text` value in the wrong delegate function. I was setting the `msg.text` in `willDisplayCell` but I had to set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.